# Why are transducers only supported on buffered channels?

Tags: clojure, core.async

It is my understanding that transducers are only allowed to be created on buffered channels. Why is this?

Comment: http://clojure-log.n01se.net/date/2015-02-26.html#13:05

Answer (score 0):

If the channel was unbuffered there would be no space between the taking and producing site to operate on the value.